# cmake, clangd, minGW, compiling troubles. Is it possible t use different libraries than the windows lib files

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, mingw, clangd

I am trying to setup a c++ build environment for developing various programs. To do so, I setup Neovim with clangD, LLVM, and minGW. An error kept creeping up stating

> Error: IOStream not found

which has lead me to an issue that I did not have cmake installed. After installing and setting up the appropriate variable paths. I was then met with this current problem

```
lld-link: error: could not open 'kernel32.lib': no such file or directory
lld-link: error: could not open 'user32.lib': no such file or directory
lld-link: error: could not open 'gdi32.lib': no such file or directory
lld-link: error: could not open 'winspool.lib': no such file or directory
lld-link: error: could not open 'shell32.lib': no such file or directory
lld-link: error: could not open 'ole32.lib': no such file or directory
lld-link: error: could not open 'oleaut32.lib': no such file or directory
lld-link: error: could not open 'uuid.lib': no such file or directory
lld-link: error: could not open 'comdlg32.lib': no such file or directory
lld-link: error: could not open 'advapi32.lib': no such file or directory
lld-link: error: could not open 'oldnames.lib': no such file or directory
lld-link: error: could not open 'msvcrtd.lib': no such file or directory
CLANG_~1: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am running Windows 10 Home edition and upon looking, these libraries are not installed on my computer.

Is there a way to install these libraries or is there another way to compile c++ with cmake so that I do not have to use the MVSC library?

I need this so I can generate a `compile_commands.json` so that neovim, clangd, llvm will work correctly.

Comment: You should reinstall Clang (+Clangd) and MinGW from [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075). Their version of Clang uses MinGW libs by default (instead of MSVC libs like the official build you're using), and not to mention all the prebuilt libraries they provide.

Comment: It's possible to use the official Clang build too, but you need to pass `--target=x86_64-w64-mingw32` every time to make it use MinGW libs (or `--target=i686-w64-mingw32` for x32).

Comment: If you're not already using CMake for your project, then adopting it just for the purpose of generating a `compile_commands.json` file for clangd seems like overkill. An easier way to generate `compile_commands.json` is with https://github.com/nickdiego/compiledb.

Comment: Let me give these a try. I am tempted to wipe slate and start from scratch to make sure everything is properly installed and pointing where it should be. 

And thanks for pointing me to the nickdiego git. hopefully this will help.

I was trying to use clangD and minGW for compiling as the setup guides for NeoVim recommended these for a working environment. I ended up at cmake as all guides I found discussing `compile_commands.json` pointed to cmake for building it.